# ar_track_alvar does not recognize tags

Tags: ros, ar-track-alvar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I have used the ar_track_alvar ROS package to recognise AR Tags.
The problem is that it only recognizes tag zero, and for all other tags, it gives wrong and very large ID and is not consistent. Sometimes it also gives wrong values for tag zero, but most often it is correct.

What could be the problem??

Thank you
Anis

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248756/ar_track_alvar-does-not-recognize-tags/) by [Anis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4199/anis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 253 on 2016-11-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It could be an issue with the camera parameters. Make sure it is calibrated and all the settings are correct and appropriate for your environment, e.g. check gain and exposure (if your camera supports these).

I usually see this issue (confusion of marker ID) when the marker is either too far away or the image is too dark/bright.

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2016-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0